# In CommCare, can you create default values in advanced modules?

Tags: commcare

I want to set up default values for a few questions in a form that is in an advanced module. I'm "manually" loading case properties by loading case properties into hidden values in the form. But when I try to set those hidden values as default values I get an error message that says I'm referencing a node in the form. Is there a way to set up default values without triggering this error?

Answer (score 2):

Default Values can not refer to other questions in the form. If you want to set the Default Value of a question to a case property you need to load the case property directly into the Default Value instead of via a Hidden Value question.

There is no difference here between normal modules and advanced modules.